# what are the coordinate vectors and dimension when working with complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

I am not sure I'm correct here:

Let $W$ be a subspace of $\;{\mathbb{C}_{[\mathbb{R}]}}$

If I have for example the vector  $$c_1=(2 + 3i)$$

the standart basis is $$E_1=\{1,i\}$$ and 
$${[{c_1}]_{{E_1}}} =\left( \begin{array}{l}2\\3\end{array} \right)$$

so I've noticed that the dimension of $$\mathbb{C}_{[\mathbb{R}]}^n = 2n$$

for example the standart basis for  $$\mathbb{C^2}_{[\mathbb{R}]}$$ is $$E_2=\left\{ {\left( \begin{array}{l}1\\0\end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{l}i\\0\end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{l}0\\1\end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{l}0\\i\end{array} \right)} \right\}$$

and for example $${c_2} = \left( \begin{array}{l}4 + 5i\\6 + 7i\end{array} \right)$$
so $${[{c_2}]_{{E_2}}} = \left( \begin{array}{l}4\\5\\6\\7\end{array} \right)$$

But what if Im working over  ${\mathbb{C}^n}$  and not over  ${\mathbb{R}^n}$ ?
what the basis will look like ? and what will be the dimension ?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{C}^n$ has dimension $2n$ when viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, and dimension $n$ when viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. An example of a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ is $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 \\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$. It's clear that these are linearly independent, and the span $\mathbb{C}^2$ because given $\begin{pmatrix}z_1 \\z_2\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{C}^2$, 
$$\begin{pmatrix}z_1 \\z_2\end{pmatrix}= z_1 \begin{pmatrix}1 \\0\end{pmatrix}+z_2 \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$
(Note that this doesn't imply $\mathbb{C}^2$ has dimension $2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ because the coefficients $z_1$ and $z_2$ are in $\mathbb{C}$, but not necessarily in $\mathbb{R}$.)
This example can be extended to show that $\mathbb{C}^n$ has dimension $n$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ works as a basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Ok, and over $\mathbb{R}$? the dimension will be 4. how the basis will look like ?

Comment: Exactly the basis that you gave in your question.

Comment: so over R I can have $i$ in the basis vectors. but over $C$ I have scalars in $C$ (which is $\;i$) so the basis is the same as $R^n$.  thanks.

Comment: You could also have $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} i\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0\\i\end{pmatrix}\right\}$ as a basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$. There's no one single basis that works, and the basis vectors don't have to have real entries. I just gave one example which shows you easily why the dimension is $n$.

Comment: ok. but over $R$ I must have $i$ in the basis because $i \notin R$

Comment: Yes, the basis over $\mathbb{R}$ cannot consist only of vectors with real number entries.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping!.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35113/discussion-between-idan-di-and-kccu).